# Asp .Net Core Razor Forms: Repopulating new collection items after failed validation

Tags: forms, validation, asp.net-core, razor

My view does not repopulate new list items that are added dynamically with the client-side script on form validation failure. ModelState holds a reference to these items before the view is returned (see Controller code example) but they do not end up in the reloaded form.

P.S. Changes to properties of existing items do get reloaded.

Is such functionality supported by the engine? If so, what is wrong with my solution? If not what is the best way to do this?

Razor File:

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Items; i++)
 {
     <div>
         @Html.Hidden("Items.Index", i)
         <input asp-for="Items[i].Property1" />
         <input asp-for="Items[i].Property2" />
     </div>
  }
  <--!  Javascript adds new divs here on demand by mimicking HTML above and incrementing i -->
```

Model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public List<SubModel> Items { get; set; }
}


public class SubModel 
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Add(MyModelCommand modelCommand)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //Dynamicaly added items are referenced in the ModelState at this point
        return View();
    }
...
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `reload form`? Do you refresh the page by F5 or using `return View(myModel);`? What is your full model, did not see any validation failed in your code. Share us a mini demo which could reproduce your issue.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the confusing bits of my question. I have clarified it.

Comment: What is `return Add();`? Should not it be `return View(model);`?

Comment: Yes, however, the view form should be repopulated from the ModelState by razor engine and there is no need to pass a model. I see how this would make sense in this example, but this is simplification and for the purpose of the question lets assume that command is passed into the controller rather than the model. Thanks for yet another good point made.

Comment: If you use `return View()`, will not you receive any error due to `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`? Why do you think, the view should render the model from `ModelState`?

Comment: This is a feature of Razor engine. It implicitly repopulates form fields from ModelState when validation fails considering that inputs are defined using tag helpers:
<input asp-for="Items[i].Property1" />

Comment: Do you develop with asp.net core mvc or asp.net core razor page template? Share us a mini demo which could reproduce your issue.

Comment: Asp.net Core. Actually - it might be a reason why repopulation fails in this case! As I query Model directly to get all the items - implicit repopulation from ModelState does not happen.

Comment: not sure what you mean.

Comment: @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Items; i++) - This line queries Model directly and has no way knowing what is in ModelState unlike the other fields that are defined by tag helpers and know how to bind to ModelState when validation fails

Comment: It's confused this `i < Model.Items` code works for you,  would not it throw error?

Comment: You are right. I do not get an Object reference exception because my view uses a component that builds the Model. If the model wouldn't be built in the component, the behaviour would be exactly as you describe it.

Comment: hope others could understand and help your issue.

Comment: I will update the question shortly to reflect this. Thanks for your feedback!